# What are the best scenarios for using object-oriented databases?

Tags: database, oop

We are planning to use OO databases to store configuration objects.
The options are:

1. Create 300+ relational tables.
2. Create a generic structure with few tables. We think this would 
   make object relation mapping more complex to build and maintain.
3. Use a OO database. We are testing this now.

What do you think ?

Comment: Some reading for you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/353258/are-object-oriented-databases-still-in-use http://stackoverflow.com/questions/52144/object-oriented-database-experiences http://stackoverflow.com/questions/246499/database-guy-asks-object-oriented-design-theory

Comment: The obvious question here is "what do the configuration objects look like?"

Comment: Depends a lot of programming language you are using.  Which language is that? Smalltalk, Java, C something?

Comment: I´ve already read that. Reading it makes me think that OO databases are good choices.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Read mostly (or single user); simple relations; constrained object graph depth; constraint management non-requirement; and relaxed object identity use cases favor the oo db.

Comment: I think this is the case. And the size of the database will be small too. Just lots of attributes/fields and classes/tables depending on the choice

Comment: In that case you can use an object db or one of the new trendy persistent key-value "db"s.  Google Redis and (plug ;) JRedis on github and see if that works for you.  

(Also for a complete left field approach [;)], take a look at Lua.  It was invented specifically to address configuration management in complex systems.  Its claimed to be the fastest scripting language out there.)

Answer (score 2):

**Object DB**

- High performance
- Faster as no joins required
- Inherent versioning mechanism
- Navigational interface for operations (like graph traversal)
- Object Query Language retrieve objects declaratively
- complex data types
- object identity ie. equals() in which object identity is independent of value and updates
- facilitates object sharing
- classes and hierarchies (inheritance and encapsulation)
- support for relationships
- integrated with a persistence language like ODL
- support for atomicity
- support for nested relationships
- semantic modelling

Cons

- No mathematical foundation as RDB (refer Codd)
- cons of object orientation
- persistence difficult for complex structures, some data must be transient

**Object-Relational databases** (You might have seen UDTs!)

- support for complex data types like collection, multisets etc
- object oriented data modelling
- extended SQL and rich types
- support for UDT inhertance
- powerful query language

Different approaches (OO, Relational DB or OODB) may be necessary for different applications

**References**

[OODMS manifesto](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/user/clamen/OODBMS/Manifesto/htManifesto/Manifesto.html)

[ODMG](http://www.odbms.org/odmg/)

[The Object-Oriented Database System Manifesto](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/afs/cs.cmu.edu/user/clamen/OODBMS/Manifesto/htManifesto/Manifesto.html)

[Object Oriented Database Systems](http://www.upriss.org.uk/db/42033lecture_one.html)

[Object Relational Databases in DBMS](http://www.slideshare.net/koolkampus/ch09)

[Completeness Criteria for Object-Relational Database Systems](http://www.slideshare.net/Databaseguys/completeness-criteria-for-objectrelational-database-systems)

**Comparisons**

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_object_database_management_systems

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_object-relational_database_management_systems